# Using recursion in Haskell to print out symbol codes and their corresponding symbols

Tags: haskell, printing, recursion, char, symbols

Like the title says I'm having some trouble printing out symbol codes and their corresponding symbols using Haskell...what I have at the moment is this:

```
import Data.Char
import Debug.Trace

foo z | trace ("Symbolcode " ++ show z ++ " is " ++ (chr z)) False = undefined
foo z = if (z <= 128)
    then foo (z+1)
    else show "All done."
```

...and I get an error like this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
In the return type of a call of `chr'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `(chr z)'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `" is " ++ (chr z)'
```

What am I doing wrong and is there an easier way of doing this (for example without using the trace module)?

Comment: How about `main = putStrLn ['\128'..]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use `trace` for anything other than debugging, because [the execution order is unreliable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Debug-Trace.html).

If you want to do something for all integers in a range, start by making the list `[0 .. 127]` of integers you want to process.  To output some text, you should use an IO action such as `putStrLn`.  Unlike `trace`, `putStrLn` will always execute when it is supposed to.  [Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Control-Monad.html) this IO action over your list to print all the characters.

```
showCharCode n = putStrLn ("Symbol code " ++ show n ++ " is " ++ [chr n])
foo = mapM_ showCharCode [0 .. 127]
```

Comment: It never hit me that he didn't want to debug the program, but wanted to use it for actual output!

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert your `Char`, as generated by `chr z`, into a `String` (For example via `[chr z]` or `return (chr z)` or `chr z : []` etc). Otherwise, you can't append it to the string before it using `++`.

```
foo z | trace ("Symbolcode " ++ show z ++ " is " ++ [chr z]) False = undefined
```